# Deploy Sharepoint Provider hosted App through CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-addin, client-object-model

I see that SharePoint is exposing below CSOM Methods.

•`Web.LoadAndInstallApp` method - Uploads and installs an app package to this site
•`Web.LoadAndInstallAppInSpecifiedLocale` method - Uploads and installs an App package, in a specified locale

•`Web.LoadApp` method - Uploads an App package and creates an instance from it.

I tried to add a provider hosted app through above `Web.LoadAndInstallApp` method. It gets installed but the Client Id and Client Secret registration is not happening. Can we perform app registration through CSOM?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now we cannot as there is no CSOM or Sharepoint online powershell commands for it.I am trying to a post with variables from the code using HttpWebRequest.

Comment: That begs the question, how come Visual Studio is able to do this? When deploying from Visual Studio, it does request and register a new App Id. Try having Fiddler running when hitting F5 in Visual Studio with your SharePoint App loaded and see what it calls out to.